# Why does google colab is enable to read my imported file from desktop?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from google.colab import files
    
    uploaded = files.upload()
    
    
    df=pd.read_csv('/content/gaming_data.csv')
    df.describe()
```

error doesn't occurs when i use sample data which is already in colab....but when i import the csv file from my pc-drive to colab then it occurs

error occurs at `df=pd.read_csv('/......')`. And i have copied the file path from the colab many times so i don't  think there is an error in the location

error is:

`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 15: unexpected end of data`

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('/content/gaming_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: no..it's encoded in windows 1252

Comment: thank you bro...i was stuck here from 2 days...... got the ans........i set encoding='windows 1252'

Comment: I added in an answer please do approve it.

Comment: just for confirmation....did i accepted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the encoding to match the `.csv` which in this case was `windows 1252`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/gaming_data.csv', encoding='windows 1252')
```